# What kind of AJAX event do you call when a POST fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Which jQuery AJAX event do you call when a post fails? For example, if the site logs this message:

`POST http://s-t-h-c.appspot.com/dispatch 500 (Internal Server Error)`

which AJAX event handler handles it? For example, if the request was successful we can use:

```
$.ajax({

success: function() {
}

});
```

I've already tried `error:` and `ajaxError:`, but they didn't seem to be able to catch the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Why don't you read the `$.ajax()` documentation?

Comment: I already did, and for some reason `error` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you add `success:` similarly there is `error:` in ajax

as a sample code I will post here one

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, textStatus ){
       alert('request successful');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert('request failed');
    }
  });
```

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! I realized I was using the wrong parameters for the `error:()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(

        {

        type: "GET",

        cache: false,

        url: url,

        dataType: "xml",

        contentType: "text/html",

        success: processData,

        error: errorAlert

        }); //end of AJax



//Package the code that handles

        //error message in case the request

        //is not successful:

        function errorAlert(e, jqxhr)

        {

        alert("Your request was not successful: " + jqxhr);

        }
```